# Qt Creator with MinGW or Visual Studio - Which one is "faster"?

Tags: performance, visual-studio, qt, mingw32

I've been using Qt Creator for about a year. Because I was new to it and was trying to get things up and running as quick as possible, I opted for the MinGW compiler. My projects have worked well enough, but I am working on one that processes a lot of data but is nonetheless processing much slower than hoped.

Before I undertake the task of installing MSVS, are there any thoughts on whether a switch to the MSVS compiler on Windows 7 generally produces a "faster" exe?

I realize there are subjective elements to this question, but I just want some general ideas.

Comment: Slow code will always be slow, no matter what compiler you're using. Try to profile and benchmark your existing code, to find the bottlenecks, and try to optimize the code at those bottlenecks. Depending on the problem, better datastructures and algorithms will also help.

Comment: Your code is the problem, not the compiler. MSVS can be faster to compile, that's the only difference.

Answer (score -1):

Ages ago, the Qt-msvc2010 builds were faster than MinGW.

It depends which Qt version, which MSVC version etc you're comparing, how you include headers, etc.

Comment: they didn't ask about the build system but how fast the .exe runs